# Jquery: Check if all links in a list have been clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making an avatar creator. The user has a list of links that they have to click on to customize the avatar options.

Under the list, is a submit button. I only want the submit button to appear when the user clicks on all the links (It is a responsive design, so this will only happen on Mobile).

How can I use Jquery to check if all the links have been clicked on then apply an "active" class to the wrapper to make the submit button appear.

NB: The links are part of a content slider, so they don't link to an external page (clicking on the links hide/shows the content on the current page).

```
<div class="wrapper not-active">

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">HairColour</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">EyeColour</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SkinColour</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HairStyle</a></li>
</ul>


<a href="#" class="submit">SUMBIT CHOICES</a>

</div>
```

I have a [JSFIDDLE Here](http://jsfiddle.net/big_smile/ddreL/3/), but I have not add any Jquery code, because I am not sure which function to use to check if all links have been clicked. (I have omitted the code for the content slider to keep things clear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.wrapper li a').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    if ($('.wrapper li a.active').length == $('.wrapper li a').length) {
        $('.wrapper').removeClass('not-active').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: All the solutions posted here are great, but this works best as it uses Wrapper classes, so I can hide the button for different devices (as opposed to all devices).

Answer (score 6):

How about adding a CSS class to each link which has been clicked, then testing how many against how many there are in total?

```
$(function() {
    var $all = $("ul li a");
    $all.click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("clicked");
        if($(".clicked").length === $all.length) {
           $(".submit").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this -

```
$('ul li a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    if ($('.clicked').length === $('ul li a').length) {
        $('.submit').show();
    }
});
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/ddreL/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
$(function(){
    var count = 0;
    $('a').on("click",function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('dummy')){
          $(this).addClass("dummy");
          count++;
        }
    });

    function submitFn(){
      var alen = $('a').length;
        if(count == alen) {
          //submit form
        }
        else{
          //throw message
        }
    }
})
```

[Jquery](http://learnhosting.org/jquery-for-beginners/)